# Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. using navigation rail

Tags: flutter

When I am trying to use navigationrail with navigator, it throws an exception:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
flutter: The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
flutter: descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pluto/pages/main_view.dart';
import 'package:pluto/pages/dash/dash_view.dart';
import 'package:pluto/pages/products/dash_info_view.dart';

GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      initialRoute: '/dashinfo',
      builder: (BuildContext context, child) => MainView(child: child!),
      routes: {
        '/dash': (BuildContext context) => const DashView(),
        '/dashinfo': (BuildContext context) => const DashInfoView(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**main_view.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainView({super.key, required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<MainView> createState() => _MainViewState();
}

class _MainViewState extends State<MainView> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('text'),
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            NavigationRail(
              labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
              selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
              onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = index;
                  if (index != 0) {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/dashinfo');
                  }
                });
              },
              destinations: [
                NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
                    label: Text('zero')),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: Text('Home1')),
              ],
            ),
            VerticalDivider(
              thickness: 1,
              width: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(child: widget.child),
          ],
        ) // the top view that does not change
        // child widget that changes
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The widgets in `builder` is above the Navigator in the widget tree, and only `BuildContext` below the Navigator can use `Navigator.pushNamed`

```
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      initialRoute: '/dashinfo',
      routes: {
        '/dash': (BuildContext context) => const MainView(child: DashView()),
        '/dashinfo': (BuildContext context) => const MainView(child: DashInfoView()),
      },
    );
```

Or

find the `context` from key if you don't want to push another `Scaffold` to the screen.

```
navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed('/dashinfo');
```

instead of

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/dashinfo');
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. But now i have a problem that it applies animation to the whole window. Is it possible to make only changed content animation?

Comment: I updated the answer, note that you only need to make one of the two changes